# getting an element from a spark dataframe and pass it to a function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to join a spark/kafka dataframe with data from Hbase, whenever an event is written to a kafka topic I want this event to be joined with info available in Hbase

my current spark streaming client looks like this:

```
val schemaOutput = new StructType()
.add("ID", StringType)
.add("RESULTID", StringType)

  val json2string: DataFrame = kafkaDF
  .select(from_json(expr("cast(value as string) as actualValue"), schemaOutput).as("s")).select("s.*").where("s.RESULTID = 6")
```

Output:

```
ID   RESULTID
 1      0
 2      1
 3      0
```

I want to do something like that:

- Define getFromHbase() function
- Get ID element from dataframe
- Pass it to GetHbase() function
- Append Hbase returned data to the dataframe

Ex:

```
   def getFromHbase( id:String) : String = {

 val return_this = ""

 if (id == "6") {
  return_this = "type 6"
 } else {
   return_this = "type else"
 }
  return return_this
}
```

Then pass dataframe ID element of each row to the function and append the return value to a column name Hbasedata

```
  val addvalue: DataFrame = json2string.withColumn("Hbasedata", getFromHbase(x))
```

Wanted output:

```
ID   RESULTID  Hbasedata
1       0       somedata
```

However I am stuck, I couldn't figure out a way to pass dataframe elements to a custom function

note: Converting Hbase to a dataframe is not an option because I want to query the data each time to make sure it is up-to date.

Comment: use UDF https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html

Comment: you can achieve it even  without own functions, just by "case when then" statements

Comment: @chlebek I don't think I can by using "case when then" the function I provided if (id == "6") return x is just an example, what I'd do in real life is Hbase connection and a query that get executed per each row in the dataframe